# Java Android - why can my debug not see into class

Tags: java, android, instantiation

I always get the below error when stepping through my code and i get to instantiating my class getMessages. with the following line:

```
final getMessages getSms = new getMessages();
```

I cant step intot he class and when not debugging the app runs ok, no errors - see below for error that pops up on new tab in eclipse. If i copy my class and rename the new copy and instantiate this it works - what gives? I spent last 4 hrs on this.

[image]

Comment: Try pasting your code here instead of in an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach source codes for Android, follow the guide here: http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/

Comment: I wrote the class, surely i should be able to debug it?

Comment: @Fearghal I know you wrote the class, but you didn't write the android framework itself. that window you are seeing is referring to the android framework's source code not yours.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you do not have the source code of that class, and the compiler only can show you what "he can find" of the class bytecode. This is not an error, only a notification that soruces are not avalaible for you to debug them

You can manually attach the source code using the "Attach Source" button, and searching for the zip file containing the jdk sources

Comment: I dont understand, the class was written by me so should i not be able to debug it?

Comment: The class that cannot be seen is the one shown on the image: `dalvik.system.DexFile` which is part of the Android SDK http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexFile.html